# How to parse a CSV without capturing erroneous delimiters?

Tags: java, regex, csv

In my program, I am given a big, massive csv `String` that I need to parse into a table of data. The data is like this:

```
["Email Address","First Name","Last Name","Phone #","Notes","Group"]
["email@email.com","First","Last","555-555-5555","Note",5]
["email2@email.com","First2","Last2","555-555-5555",null,3]
```

(to make a MVCE on this, you can use this:)

```
String text = "[\"Email Address\",\"First Name\",\"Last Name\",\"Phone #\",\"Notes\",\"Group\"]\n" +
    "[\"email@email.com\",\"First\",\"Last\",\"555-555-5555\",\"Note\",5]\n" +
    "[\"email2@email.com\",\"First2\",\"Last2\",\"555-555-5555\",null,3]";
```

The first line are the table headers and the subsequent lines are the values. Each line is enclosed in `[` and `]` and the values are comma separated.

I need to:

1. Separate the lines
2. Separate each value

For #1, I think this approach is good:

```
Pattern eachLinePattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*\\][\r\n]+");
Matcher matcher = eachLinePattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String line = matcher.group().trim();
}
```

This regex will capture everything (`.*`) between `[` and `]` that is followed by a `\n` or `\r`, which should be sufficient to capture all the lines (this sounds like a statement, but it is a question. Am I missing a potential pitfall on this?)

For #2, this is where I am having difficulty. Some items are strings (`""`) and some are not (`null`, #s, etc.).

My first idea was to do a `.split()` using commas as the delimeter:

```
Pattern eachLinePattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*\\][\r\n]+");
Matcher matcher = eachLinePattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String line = matcher.group().trim();
    String[] eachItem = line.split(",");
    for(String item : eachItem)
        System.out.println(item);
}
```

But, this has the obvious side-effect of, also, capturing commas in the data. So, how do I make sure the commas in the data don't get captured as false delimiters?

Comment: Not sure what you can do if your value delimiter is potentially also found in the values themselves.  Perhaps try using `","` as the delimiter and remove the opening `"` from the first element and the closing `"` from the last element - just a thought - **update** still unsure as to how to handle null values but that could be a pre-processing step (i.e. replace null with empty string)

Comment: @ochi, the CSV format is out of my control. :/ it's parse it or die.

Comment: Got it. So, before you `.split()` replace null with `""` (assuming null is the word inserted in that case) or insert an empty string inside two consecutive commas... etc.

Comment: @ochi, doesn't solve the problem of the numbers, though. There are more non-string values in the dataset than just `null`s.

Comment: true... is the dataset always in the same format? are the non-string values always the last element of the 'row'? - failing some standard line delimiters, you may have to make some assumptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to do this yourself? [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library is one option I've used for parsing CSV files (there are [others](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)). There are a surprising number of corner cases in parsing delimited text, and someone else has already done it better than you ever will.

Comment: I'm open to trying a new API. Never had to do any complicated parsing before (and, idk if I'd even call -this- complicated). I'll give it a look